# Disable IMAP Logging Out in Python

Tags: python, email, timeout, runtime-error, imap

Okay, so I decided today that I wanted to delete all the old emails out of my old email account. Now I have around about 40,000+ emails I need to delete, so I took the obvious approach and made a script to do this for me.

Everything was working fine for about **10 minutes** till I hit a snag where IMAP gives a Loggout error. The code runs fine, I just need to know if there's a way to disable this or bypass it so I can run this script until all my emails are deleted.

Here's the script (With username and password changed for obvious reasons):

```py
import imaplib
import email
from tqdm import tqdm
from email.header import decode_header

# Account credentials
username = "username@domain.com"
password = "password"

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.mail.yahoo.com")
imap.login(username, password)

imap.select("Archive")

status, messages = imap.search(None, "ALL")
messages = messages[0].split(b' ')
amtOfMessages = len(messages)

print("Clearing all emails in the ARCHIVE folder")
print("Total emails in folder: ", amtOfMessages)

#tqdm is a library I'm using to display a progress bar in the cmd line
for i in tqdm(range(amtOfMessages)):
    _, msg = imap.fetch(messages[i], "(RFC822)")
    imap.store(messages[i], "+FLAGS", "\\Deleted")

imap.expunge()
imap.close()
imap.logout()

print("ALL MESSAGES DELETED FROM ARCHIVE FOLDER")
print("Logged out of account...")
```

Finally, here is the traceback of the error that I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Documents/EmailScripts/quickstart.py", line 27, in <module>
    _, msg = imap.fetch(messages[i], "(RFC822)")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 548, in fetch
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 1049, in _command_complete
    raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.abort: command: FETCH => IMAP4rev1 Server logging out
```

Edit: Misspoke when saying 'Timeout.' Meant to say Logout. Changes have been made.

Comment: Why are you fetching the message just to delete it?  If all you want to do is empty the folder, issue the simple command: imap.store(‘1:*’, ‘+FLAGS’, ‘\\Deleted’); imap.expunge()

Comment: I was using that because the tutorial I was looking at was using it. But thanks mate, I'm gonna try that out and see if I run into the same problem.